# How many tickets sold at a concert

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The music department of a school sold 750 tickets to the school concert, for a total of \$4755. Students paid \$5 for a ticket and non-students paid \$8 for a ticket. How many non-students attended the concert? I'm not sure what equations to use to get this answer.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, please edit your title to be more descriptive for the post.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't (analytical-geometry).

Answer (score 2):

**Basic approach.** Think about what you don't know: You don't know how the purchased tickets were distributed amongst students and non-students.  So use variables to denote them—$s$ for the number of students who bought tickets, and $n$ for the number of *non*-students who bought tickets.

What equation would represent the fact that the total number of tickets equals $750$?

Now what expression (*not* equation) would represent the money spent by students on tickets?  For instance, if $s = 7$, then those $7$ students collectively spent $7 \times 5 = 35$ dollars.  How would you make that more general, in terms of $s$?

How would you do that for the $n$ non-students?

Then add those two expressions up, and find an equation to represent the fact that the total amount of money spent on tickets equals $4755$ dollars.

Now you have two equations, which you can solve to determine $s$ and $n$, the latter quantity being what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put this on equation.

"Students paid $\$$5 for a ticket and non-students paid $\$$8 for a ticket", so the total earned money is $5t_1+8t_2=4755$, where $t1$ is the number of students, and $t_2$ is the number of non-students. Plus, you know that the total number of tickets is $750$, so $t1+t2=750$. You are left with one equation depending only on $t_2$, then you can find $t_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ bet the number of student tickets and $N$ be the number of non-student tickets.  Then you know that
$$
n+N = 750
$$
and 
$$
5n+8N=4755
$$
This is two equations with two unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the amount of non-students $n$. Then we know the amount of non-students is $750-n$ (since the total number of people is $750$). So all non-students together paid $8\cdot n$ dollar, and all students together paid $(750-n)\cdot 5$ dollars. Together, that is $4755$ dollar, so

$$8n+5(750-n)=4755$$

Now we can simplify this, to get

$$8n+5\cdot 750-5\cdot n=3n+3750=4755$$

so that

$$3n=1005$$

and dividing both sides by $3$ yields

$$n=335$$

so the total number of non-students is $335$.

Answer (score 0):

If all tickets were sold to students they would have gain $5\cdot750= 3750$ bucks.  As they gained $4755$ bucks, the remaining income of $1005$ dollars is due the non students.  As each of them paid three dollars more then a student there must be $1005:3=335$ non students.